# EasyAPNS configuration

Tags: ios

Hey I'm building an App on iOS and want to implement PushNotifications.
I am using the EasyAPNS code from https://github.com/manifestinteractive/easyapns 
When configuring it, I have to obviously add my Mysql-Database information in the DB_Connect php file. I am not good with php, so I don't really have a clue here as to how exactly I have to enter my information in the file because in the tutorials I'va watched the file always looked different. Can you guys give me any guidance as to how to proceed? Thnaks, oengelha.

Here the code snippet:

```
/**
    * Constructor. Initializes a database connection and selects our database.
    * @param string $host       The host to wchich to connect.
    * @param string $username   The name of the user used to login to the database.
    * @param string $password   The password of the user to login to the database.
    * @param string $database   The name of the database to which to connect.
    */
    function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database)
    {
        $this->DB_HOST     = $host;
        $this->DB_USERNAME = $username;
        $this->DB_PASSWORD = $password;
        $this->DB_DATABASE = $database;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->DB_HOST     = 'Your Host';
    $this->DB_USERNAME = 'Your Username'; // !!! CHANGE ME
    $this->DB_PASSWORD = 'Your Password'; // !!! CHANGE ME
    $this->DB_DATABASE = 'Your Database'; // !!! CHANGE ME
}
```

Best of luck!